# Error on using SideBar for openlayers

Tags: openlayers, sidebar

Good afternoon

I'm using the [sidebar](https://github.com/Turbo87/sidebar-v2) for OpenLayers, but using ol.js directly from the site (// openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js" ) started to present the following error:

> ReferenceError: undefined $ `o` is not defined [Learn More] Projection.js: 80: 2
>   _and
>   Projection.js: 80: 2
>   If
>   epsg3857.js: 52: 2
>   
>   epsg3857.js: 73: 2
>   
>   http://openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js:1:2

That since Thursday, 06/22/2018.

Has any modification been made to this js?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, there are some changes due to upcoming OpenLayers V5.0 release that seem to break the demo.

So, you should replace the references to OpenLayers to v4.6.5

For css, instead of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//openlayers.org/en/master/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

use

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

and for JavaScript, replace

```
<script src="//openlayers.org/en/master/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

with

```
<script src="//openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```